# I am trying to remove all special characters from a string and the below works fine except it is removing the space between words

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here I am trying to remove all special characters from a string and this working fine except it is removing the spaces between the words as well.I need the spaces in between the words.

```
NSCharacterSet *charactersToRemove = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];

    dataString = [[dataString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: You could make it `NSMutableCharacterSet` and call `[charactersToRemove removeCharactersInString:@" "]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a NSMutableCharacterSet like in this example:

```
NSMutableCharacterSet * charactersToRemove = [NSMutableCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
[charactersToRemove addCharactersInString:@" "];

NSCharacterSet *newCharactersToRemove = [charactersToRemove invertedSet];
```